# Disposing of Elements in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am automating some tasks with the help of a database and WPF C# applications. One such task is monthly reporting, looking at activity from the previous month. I am using DateTime pickers to pick a start and end date for the reporting, but usually it will be the first and last day of whatever month. In my view model I have binding properties to the begin date time and the end date time, and they default to the first and last day of the previous month. When I pick a new start day, I have code that will make it the first day of the picked month, and then set the end day to the last day of the month like so:

```
private DateTime _d1 = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month - 1, 1); //First Day of previous month
private DateTime _d2 = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddDays(-1); //Last Day of previous month
public DateTime d1
    {
        get { return _d1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _d1)
            {
                _d1 = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, 1);
                _d2 = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month + 1, 1).AddDays(-1);
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("d1");
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("d2");
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is this: the old `DateTime` that `_d1` was referencing (same for `_d2`) is still allocated out there somewhere. Is there a way for me to dereference that block of memory before assigning a new one? I figure that garbage collection probably does this, but it seems strange to me to leave things dangling like that. Coming from a C/C++ background, I feel that this is definitely not ok.

Comment: No; the garbage collector does everything for you.  (plus, that's a value type anyway)

Comment: As an aside, you can't reliably add months in this way, because the `months` parameter has to be 1 through 12.  Use the `AddMonths` method instead.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks . . . I am now seeing more pitfalls in my date logic as well, glad you pointed that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `DateTime` you are fine. Its all managed memory and the GC will get it.

You *do* need to be careful about this with objects that use unmanaged resources, specifically, if they implement `IDisposable`.

For such objects, you should call `Dispose` when you are done with them or use them in a `using` block so they will be disposed when they leave scope:

```
using (var someDisposable = new DisposableObject())
{
   //do stuff with someDisposable
}
```

`Bitmap` is a good example of a class that will bite you if you forget this :) It holds a large un-managed GDI bitmap that will take *forever* to clear if you don't manually dispose it.